# Clone ubuntu linux hard disk

Tags: ubuntu, hard-drive

I have 2 160GB drives in a server.  One is the OS, the other data.

I want to clone these drives to two new 1TB drives.

What is the best way to go about this ?

Thanks

EDIT:

I used clonezilla to clone the drive, however now i need to resize the partition to fill this disk.

So far this is all i have found.

http://sourceforge.net/projects/clonezilla/forums/forum/663168/topic/3750321

EDIT 2:

```
PV         VG      Fmt  Attr PSize   PFree
  /dev/sda1  AO-0023 lvm2 a-   148.81g    0
  /dev/sdb1  AO-0023 lvm2 a-   149.05g    0
```

/dev/sda1 is actually a 1TB drive now.

sudo fdisk -l

```
Disk /dev/sdb: 160.0 GB, 160041885696 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 19457 cylinders
Units = cylinders of 16065 * 512 = 8225280 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x2c9c2c9b

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sdb1               1       19457   156288321   83  Linux

Disk /dev/sda: 1000.2 GB, 1000204886016 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 121601 cylinders
Units = cylinders of 16065 * 512 = 8225280 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0xd42ad42a

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1   *           1       19426   156039313+  8e  Linux LVM
/dev/sda2           19427       19457      249007+   5  Extended
/dev/sda5           19427       19457      248976   83  Linux
```

Comment: Are these drives going to replace the existing ones?

Comment: Yes, i want to replace them.

Comment: Is the system currently using LVM?

Comment: Yes, it is using LVM

Answer (score 4):

Since the system is using LVM, you can convert the new drives into PVs (either whole disk or partitions is fine, but you should mimic the existing structure), then use `vgextend` to absorb them into the existing VG, `pvmove` to move the LVs from the old PVs to the new PVs, `vgreduce` to remove the old PVs from the VG, then reinstall the bootloader on the new drives.

Comment: I ended up using clonezilla, although your solution sounds much nicer.  Now i need to extend my partitions to use all the free space.

Comment: What do your new PVs,VGs and LVs look like now?

Comment: I'll update main post

Answer (score 3):

```
dd if=/dev/sda of=/dev/sdc bs=32768 # bigger block size for speed
dd if=/dev/sdb of=/dev/sdd bs=32768
resize2fs /dev/sdc
resize2fs /dev/sdd
```

(old disks=`sda` and `sdb`, new disks=`sdc` and `sdd`)

Comment: I made an assumptions here that will be false in a near future. I consider that your disk use an MBR, future disk (>2TB) will not any more be usable with standard MBR and this solution will not work any more.

Answer (score 0):

you try following link

http://studyhat.blogspot.com/2010/11/clone-redhat-cent-os-fedora.html