# Resize LVM after cloning disk

Tags: partition, lvm

I have cloned a 160Gb disk onto a 1TB disk.

See here for the exact details.
[Clone ubuntu linux hard disk](https://serverfault.com/questions/205387/clone-ubuntu-linux-hard-disk)

I want the use the entire disk.

How do i get the volume to use the whole disk.

There where some suggestions in the previous post and i have googled around,  But i'm not confident what is the best way forward.

Thanks

> $ sudo fdisk -l
>
> ```
> Disk /dev/sda: 1000.2 GB, 1000204886016 bytes
> 255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 121601 cylinders
> Units = cylinders of 16065 * 512 = 8225280 bytes
> Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
> I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
> Disk identifier: 0xd42ad42a
>
>    Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
> /dev/sda1   *           1       19426   156039313+  8e  Linux LVM
> /dev/sda2           19427       19457      249007+   5  Extended
> /dev/sda5           19427       19457      248976   83  Linux
>
> Disk /dev/sdb: 160.0 GB, 160041885696 bytes
> 255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 19457 cylinders
> Units = cylinders of 16065 * 512 = 8225280 bytes
> Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
> I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
> Disk identifier: 0x2c9c2c9b
>
>    Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
> /dev/sdb1               1       19457   156288321   83  Linux
>
> $ sudo pvdisplay
>   --- Physical volume ---
>   PV Name               /dev/sda1
>   VG Name               AO-0023
>   PV Size               148.81 GiB / not usable 2.14 MiB
>   Allocatable           yes (but full)
>   PE Size               4.00 MiB
>   Total PE              38095
>   Free PE               0
>   Allocated PE          38095
>   PV UUID               9QOBa4-SKHd-P82d-LDi7-gYh6-6hT8-2eezF1
>
>   --- Physical volume ---
>   PV Name               /dev/sdb1
>   VG Name               AO-0023
>   PV Size               149.05 GiB / not usable 1.31 MiB
>   Allocatable           yes (but full)
>   PE Size               4.00 MiB
>   Total PE              38156
>   Free PE               0
>   Allocated PE          38156
>   PV UUID               yeBtIS-UrEE-9Is8-QkEC-Rzl3-s7RL-gVvReI
>
>
> ~$ sudo lvdisplay
>   --- Logical volume ---
>   LV Name                /dev/AO-0023/root
>   VG Name                AO-0023
>   LV UUID                rc2Nwi-gxSQ-S2lZ-GOS1-af2g-mSR9-rAYsCm
>   LV Write Access        read/write
>   LV Status              available
>   # open                 1
>   LV Size                143.12 GiB
>   Current LE             36640
>   Segments               1
>   Allocation             inherit
>   Read ahead sectors     auto
>   - currently set to     256
>   Block device           251:0
>
>   --- Logical volume ---
>   LV Name                /dev/AO-0023/swap_1
>   VG Name                AO-0023
>   LV UUID                CzZtTB-hpDT-G7co-OvZ7-Xa4K-IpOq-tyuz1H
>   LV Write Access        read/write
>   LV Status              available
>   # open                 1
>   LV Size                5.68 GiB
>   Current LE             1455
>   Segments               1
>   Allocation             inherit
>   Read ahead sectors     auto
>   - currently set to     256
>   Block device           251:1
>
>   --- Logical volume ---
>   LV Name                /dev/AO-0023/copy
>   VG Name                AO-0023
>   LV UUID                kKpe1x-OtsI-vvJu-t5Ei-jhOt-ufLC-s1GsRh
>   LV Write Access        read/write
>   LV Status              available
>   # open                 1
>   LV Size                149.05 GiB
>   Current LE             38156
>   Segments               1
>   Allocation             inherit
>   Read ahead sectors     auto
>   - currently set to     256
>   Block device           251:2
>
> $ sudo vgdisplay
>   --- Volume group ---
>   VG Name               AO-0023
>   System ID
>   Format                lvm2
>   Metadata Areas        2
>   Metadata Sequence No  5
>   VG Access             read/write
>   VG Status             resizable
>   MAX LV                0
>   Cur LV                3
>   Open LV               3
>   Max PV                0
>   Cur PV                2
>   Act PV                2
>   VG Size               297.86 GiB
>   PE Size               4.00 MiB
>   Total PE              76251
>   Alloc PE / Size       76251 / 297.86 GiB
>   Free  PE / Size       0 / 0
>   VG UUID               J4wgRy-EaDi-07A0-0Wyc-6IOG-dt82-Pdcics
> ```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You grow LVM by either:

- Resizing the underlying block device and running `pvresize`, or
- Adding additional PVs to your volume group.

Your disk information above is a little unclear, so I'm going to ignore it and give you a general description of the procedure.  If your 1TB disk is otherwise empty, except for the LVM partition, then you can simply:

- Use `fdisk` to increase the size of the partition
- Use `pvresize` to grow the LVM PV to match the size of the partition.

If you're mixing LVM PVs on your disk with other partitions...don't do that.  But if you insist, you can create an additional partition covering the extra space, and then add it to your volume group:

- `pvcreate /dev/sd??`
- `vgextend vg0 /dev/sd??`